# How to show out null value using NVL Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to select out a list of customer with their total purchases amount made.

The sum of the purchase_amount must not include the 'void' and 'failed' status amount

Currently, I have the sql script as below but the customer who make the 'failed' and 'void' status didn't show out.

Which part am I doing wrong?

Script:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME, NVL(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) AS PURCHASE_AMOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION T ON T.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE T.STATUS NOT IN('Void', 'Failed')
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME;
```

[image]
[image]

**Actual Result:**
[image]

**Expected Result:**
[image]

Comment: use the condition in the ON clause

Comment: And use `customer` as a left table

Comment: @astentx I have use the customer table as the left table now already ya

Comment: If you combine both the above comments, you'll get desired output

Comment: The author still needs customer names for void and failed statuses in expected output

Comment: @4yz `right join` (or `left join` with swapped tables) would fulfill the requirement

Comment: @astentx, wont swapped left join with status predicate result in customer_id = c2 having null as customer name?

Comment: @4yz Why? Left join returns all rows from the left table.

Comment: @astentx, nevermind. I just looked to the sql in question (which has it already swapped probably), and misread your initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of the condition `T.STATUS NOT IN('Void', 'Failed')` in the WHERE clause effectively turns the LEFT JOIN of the TRANSACTION table into an inner join, because no row can be accepted if the condition in the WHERE clause is not satisfied. To have the `T.STATUS...` condition treated as part of the LEFT JOIN it must appear in the ON clause of the join itself:

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME, NVL(SUM(AMOUNT), 0) AS PURCHASE_AMOUNT
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION T
  ON T.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID AND
     T.STATUS NOT IN('Void', 'Failed')
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID, C.NAME;
```

Comment: You can also write
"and lnnvl( t.status <> 'Success' )" instead of "T.STATUS NOT IN('Void', 'Failed')"
and I would put the NVL() inside the SUM because if you have both 'Success' and 'Failed'|'Void' transactions for the same customer the SUM(amount) will be nullified, which is not the expected result.
(the test data doesn't cover this situation)

Comment: @p3consulting It is less clear and not the same: you define a set of allowed statuses, while the question defines a set of disallowed statuses. Aggregate function returns`null` only if all the values are `null`, so it doesn't matter where to put `nvl`

Answer (score 0):

You can check 'T.STATUS' with CASE in select part instead of checking it in where clause.

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    c.name,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN t.status NOT IN('Void', 'Failed') THEN
                amount
            ELSE
                0
        END
    ) AS purchase_amount
FROM
    customer    c
    LEFT JOIN transaction t ON t.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id,
    c.name;
```